# Reflection Exception : Class ClassName doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I am using Laravel 5.5. I have added a custom directory inside App folder in my workspace. So, the folder structure is:

Inside `App\Bishwa\Transformers` there are two PHP files:

1. Transformer.php
2. LessonTransformer.php

Those files look like follows:

1. Transformer.php

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Bishwa;

   abstract class Transformer {

       public function transformCollection(array $items){

           return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);

       }

       public abstract function transform($item);
   }
   ```
2. LessonTransformer.php

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Bishwa;

   class LessonTransformer extends Transformer {



       public function transform($lesson){

           return [
               'title' => $lesson['title'],
               'body' => $lesson['body'],
               'active' => (boolean)$lesson['some_bool']
           ];
   }

   }
   ```

Then Inside LessonsController.php I have the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\Lesson;
use Bishwa\LessonTransformer;

class LessonsController extends Controller
{
    protected $lessonTransformer;

    function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer){
        dd('ok');
    
}
```

While running action of the controller, It gave me an error message saying:

```
Reflection Exception: Class Bishwa\LessonTransformer does not exist
```

I have tried `composer dump-autoload`, restarting the server again but none of them helped. Am I doing wrong while Namespacing or What?

Comment: Have you added the namespace to the autoloaders in your `composer.json`?

Comment: Thanks for that.. Its my silly mistake :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to Jerodev and Jack. Since, both of them were write I decided to write myself a combined solution to this problem.

1st Solution:

In case of custom namespaces and custom classes I have to include the path to classname in `Composer.json` file in the following portion:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
             "app/Bishwa/Transformers"


        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
```

2nd Solution:

Changing NameSpace of my files to custom directory `App\Bishwa` .

Namespace of transformer.php and LessonTransformer.php now becomes:

```
namespace App\Bishwa\Transformers;
```

While using in LessonsController:

```
use App\Bishwa\Transformers\LessonTransformer;
```

Once again, big thanks to Jerodev and Jack. Its my silly mistake, that I couldn't figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Change your namespace of the files in your custom directory to `App\Bishwa`.